# C++ <policy-file-request />

Tags: c++, sockets, flash

hopefully this will be my last C++ question related to sockets.
I have a .SWF file and it sends a policy file request.

I check if my incoming data char 0 is <, so like this:

```
if (raw[0] == '<')
```

Then I send my policy shit:

```
            send(this->s, Env::Policy().c_str(), sizeof(Env::Policy()), 0);

            std::cout << "Sent " << Env::Policy().c_str() << std::endl;
            running = false;
            closesocket(this->s);
            break;
```

break; will stop the while (this->running) loop.
My policy string:

```
std::string Env::Policy()
{
    char c = 0;

    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\r\n<cross-domain-policy>\r\n<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"1-31111\" />\r\n</cross-domain-policy>" + c;
}
```

But every time I send it, nothing happens. The socket won't receive a new connection (like in C# socket server). But when I reconnect on the .swf, it will accept a new connection.
What's going on?

My full while(this->running) loop:

```
while (running)
{
    char c[256];

    int bits = recv(s, c, sizeof(c), 0);

    if (bits > 0)
    {
        std::string data = c;
        std::string raw = data.substr(0, bits);

        std::cout << "First char: " << raw[0] << std::endl;

        if (raw[0] == '<')
        {
            send(this->s, Env::Policy().c_str(), sizeof(Env::Policy()), 0);

            std::cout << "Sent " << Env::Policy().c_str() << std::endl;
            running = false;
            closesocket(this->s);
            break;
        }

        int header = Env::B64Decode(raw.substr(3, 2));

        switch (header)
        {
        case 202:
            this->msg = new ServerMessage("DA");
            this->msg->AddInt32(6);
            this->msg->AddInt32(0);
            this->msg->AddInt32(1);
            this->msg->AddInt32(1);
            this->msg->AddInt32(1);
            this->msg->AddInt32(3);
            this->msg->AddInt32(0);
            this->msg->AddInt32(2);
            this->msg->AddInt32(1);
            this->msg->AddInt32(4);
            this->msg->AddInt32(1);
            this->msg->AddString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            this->msg->AddChar(2);
            this->sendData(this->msg->toString());

            this->msg = new ServerMessage("@H");
            this->msg->AddString("[100,105,110,115,120,125,130,135,140,145,150,155,160,165,170,175,176,177,178,180,185,190,195,200,205,206,207,210,215,220,225,230,235,240,245,250,255,260,265,266,267,270,275,280,281,285,290,295,300,305,500,505,510,515,520,525,530,535,540,545,550,555,565,570,575,580,585,590,595,596,600,605,610,615,620,625,626,627,630,635,640,645,650,655,660,665,667,669,670,675,680,685,690,695,696,700,705,710,715,720,725,730,735,740]");
            this->msg->AddChar(2);
            this->sendData(this->msg->toString());
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unregistered header " << header << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 std::string data = c;
```

is only good if the string is surely 0-terminated

```
 std::string raw = data.substr(0, bits);
```

you could do that simpler

```
 const std::string raw(c, c+bits);
```

in your policy function there's a char c for no reason, but if it had value >0, would likely cause problems.

And most importantly, sending `sizeof(Env::Policy())` bytes makes no sense at all, you shall send the whole string!

```
const auto& policy = Env::Policy();
send(this->s, policy, policy.size() + 1, 0);
```

maybe without +1, depending if you want the 0.

Comment: The policy response is sended with chr(0) at the end.